# I changed my name in minecraft and cant login

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I changed my minecraft name and tried to login to the techninc launcher but it said the name was invalid. I know its not since i was able to login in vanilla minecraft but only through the e-mail option and not the username option. Does anyone know how to fix this since the technic launcher does not give me the option to log in through e-mail?

Comment: I can't test right now, but I'm pretty sure you can just put your email in the spot in the Technic Launcher that says Username and have it work just fine.  When you migrate your Minecraft login to your Mojang account, your username just becomes your email address.  It ~IS~ your username.

Comment: Keep in mind that it's not really an "option" of how you log in. If you've migrated, you **need** to use your email, if you haven't, you **need** to use your username.

Comment: i tried, but it didnt work:(

Comment: what does it mean to migrate your account?

Comment: @PhilipAdams If you have an email address for your account, migrating doesn't matter to you. It's a way for people with old accounts to start using the new email-address style of account.

Comment: That aside, I have a question: how old is your Technic Launcher?! Technic has been able to understand email address accounts for a long time now.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1

As soon as you change it leave it a 1-24 hours for it to be verifyed. (Easy way of putting it)

Option 2
Check your email its possible you could have been sent a email asking you to click a link to verify it.

Comment: i can try and leave it for tomarrow but ive already verifyed the username

Comment: Migration is instant and does not involve clicking a link in a confirmation email, so waiting isn't necessary or useful and neither is checking your email.

Comment: Sometimes it will email you waiting for verifcation what I said is correct it has happened search it up if you must